# Creative Programming

Tags: code-challenge

Make a story out of your programming.
Example in JavaScript:

```
self.book = {
    "story": function() {
        var once = "upon",
            aTime = setTimeout(function() {
                // Code would continue...
            }, 1000)
    }
};

self.book.story();
```

**Stipulations:**

- Must run error-free before, during, and after it's compiled.
- You can only use up to two words for the story per String/name.

  - JavaScript Example: 
    `var story = "Once upon a"; // Wrong (Using more than two words)`
    `var story = "Onceupona"; // Wrong (Using more than two "words")`
    `var onceUponA = "time"; // Wrong (more than two words as a variable name)`
    `var onceUpon = "a time"; // This is fine`
    `var story = "Once upon"; // This is fine`
- The story must be a complete sentence (at least).
- Having some sort of output (such as "printing" the story itself) is not necessary, but it's a plus.
- Bring some creativity into it.

Since there are no length rules, the answer with the most votes / best creativity will win. :)

Comment: This sort of reminds me of [this IOCCC entry](http://www0.us.ioccc.org/1990/westley.c), which is written as an exchange of letters

Comment: I hope you mean only up to 2 words in string literals? Otherwise combining strings would be illegal.

Comment: @jpjacobs Yup. Though something like `"Hi how" + "are you" + "doing today"` would be lame. ;)

Comment: No objective winning criteria.

Comment: [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/) published [a creative job offer for their Russian office](http://habrastorage.org/storage1/b1d4a46c/08e6d914/03b7857d/fa1f4274.jpg).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## JavaScript

Not sure how historically accurate this, but it's a mini-history of ECMAScript. Please feel free to suggest improvements.

```
function story() {
    var IE = {
        from: "Microsoft"
    },
        Netscape = {
            from: "Mozilla"
        };
    var setUp = {
        oncethere: "were two",
        browsers: IE + Netscape
    };
    var parts = {

        And: function() {
            var theyfought = "to be",
                theBest = "browser";
        },
        oneday: function() {
            var they = {
                added: function() {
                    var add = "scripting languages";
                    Netscape.language = add;
                    IE.language = add;
                    return add;
                },
                thought: function() {
                    if (what(they.added) === good) {
                        they.wouldBeat = "the other";
                    }
                }
            };

        },
        andso: function() {
            function callLanguage(name) { return name };
            Netscape.language = callLanguage("Javascript");
            IE.language = callLanguage("JScript");
        },
        butThen: function() {
            var ECMA = "Standards Committee";
            (function standardized(languages) {
                (function into() {
                    return "ECMAScript";
                })();
            })([IE.language, Netscape.language]);

        },
        theEnd: function() {
            return {
                andWe: "all lived",
                happilyEver: "after..."
            };
        },
        what: function(thing) {
            return thing;
        },
        good: true || false
    };
}
story();
```

Comment: Now there's a JavaScript Book. ;)

Comment: @Shaz HA yup. Imagine a book explaining JS written like that. O_o

Comment: Yeah it would certainly be interesting. :P  I'm just glad English is my native language.

Answer (score 14):

Reminds me of [LOLCode](http://lolcode.com/examples/count-1), everything is sort of a story (or at least a "conversation"):

```
HAI
CAN HAS STDIO?
I HAS A VAR
IM IN YR LOOP
    UPZ VAR!!1
    VISIBLE VAR
    IZ VAR BIGR THAN 10? GTFO. KTHX
KTHX
KTHXBYE
```

Comment: Interesting never heard of LOLCode. However, can you come up with something original or is this the only syntax available? o.O

Comment: That reminds me of Shakespeare programming language. lol.

Comment: lol yeah lmfao http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakespeare_(programming_language)

Comment: Downvoted for being neither interesting nor innovative. Should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @cemper93 You should flag it as Not An Answer. And probably flag the question for not meeting the guidelines about objective winning criteria.

Comment: "flag this post for serious problems or moderator attention" - that kind of scares me away ;) And I like the question even though it is subjective. It's interesting, and I don't think you have to always have an objective winning criterion. Look at the Code Golfs: Everyone knows in advance Golfscript will be the winner, yet there are other entries. If everyone would only play by objectiveness, this site would soon be dead.

Answer (score 14):

## JavaScript

```
'How';do{'computers'^Function}while(0);'they have'|'no power?'
```

The output is: `0` on console :D

Comment: I like this. :)

Comment: `this.is,2,'show my',/appreciation/`

Comment: What console? Perhaps you should indicate which language you used.

Comment: It's JavaScript just paste it into `firebug`/`console`.

Comment: Doesn't do anything here. Or is it just me?

Comment: Both Firefox and Chrome output zero because of the bitwise operators... Not sure what you are using

Answer (score 13):

It's not so much of a *story*, and what the program does has nothing to do with what the code says, but...

## C++

```
/* Preface (assuming nobody reads it anyway): */
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int



/*Beginning   the*/ main(){//story:

#define   a   string
ofstream ing___water;   a   river;

#define   the
long   rivers,
each,  is
(a ( river +"of").length() > 4 );
a   normal ( river +"has   the");
a bility;   for ( float ing;  short (~1 - - 2 );){
char coal,  loaded,  ships,  on,  its,  water;
coal = is;  a   lot,   lighter;
if ( lighter  .compare ( normal ))water = 'H'*2+'O'; }

a   heavier,  ship,  may;  do { a   worse,  job;  a nd,  run;
a ground; }while ( "you"&&false)//ly
;try { a nd ( "navigate   through");
a ny, such ( normal.size()==rivers     ? 

the  "ship" : may + "then"); }
catch ( exception ally ) { a wful;}} struct ural___damage {
long   before ( the   time_t o)                                                                                               const{
return "to" == a( "harbour");
for ( a   rescue ("from   leaking"),
its ("load   or");o<the'r';) {
ofstream ing,  substances;
if ("not"=="even"||substances/*that*/.put( 'a').bad())
double   damage,  to,  both   the ((short) "river"[1]);
a nd   the ("overall   environment[2].");}}

a   sentient,  ship_owner,  should,  h;int //to
the operator<( struct ural___damage   might)                                                                                  const{
a lso( "occur"), to( "his   own"),health( "when   not");
using   the ::map;
to  .find(  a ( "river   that's"),long( ~3 ) );
(to+="avoid")+=the "trouble   and";
(to+="cause")+=(less</*r*/ural___damage>()
(*this,/*seems like*/*this)?"is": a( "good   idea"));


return before ( the   time(0))||"is"==to +"late";}};
```

As plain text:

> Beginning the main story:
>  
>    
> define a string ofstreaming water a river;
> define the long rivers, each is a river of length > 4;
> a normal river has the ability for floating short (~1--2) charcoal-loaded ships on its water; coal is a lot lighter if lighter compare normal water = H2O;
> a heavier ship may do a worse job and run aground while you falsely try and navigate through any such normalsize rivers, the  ship may then
> catch exeptionally awful structural damage long before the time to<sub>const</sub> return to a harbour for a rescue from leaking its load or other ofstreaming substances, if not even substances that put a bad double damage to both the short river [1] and the overall environment[2].
> a sentient ship_owner should hint to the operator structural damage might<sub>const</sub> also occur to his own health when not using the map to find a river   that's long(~3) to avoid the trouble and to cause less rural damage. this seems like this is a good idea.
>
>
> return before the time is to late.

Answer (score 12):

## Brainfuck

```
+++++ +   + +++++ +++++ +++++   +++++ +++++ 
  +   +   + +     +   + +         +   +     
  +   +++++ +++   +++++ +++       +   +++++ 
  +   +   + +     + ++  +         +       . 
  +   +   + +++++ +   + +++++   +++++ +++++ 

+++++ +   + +     +   +   +++++ +   + +.+++ 
[   + ]+  + +      + +    +   + ++  + +     
+   + + [ + ]       +     +   + + + + +++   
+   + +  ++ +       +     +   + +  ++ +     
+++++ +   + +++++   +     ++++. +   + +++++ 

++++  +++++ +++++ +++++  +   +              
+   + +   + +   +   +    ++  +              
++++  +++++ +++++   +    + + +              
+   + + +   +   +   +    +  ++     +        
++++  +   + +   + +.[+]  +   +    +         

+++++ +   + +++++ +   + +++++ +++++ +++++ . 
+     +   + +     +  +  +     +   + +     + 
+++   +   + +     +++   +++   +++++ +++++ + 
+     +   + +     +  +  +     + ++      +   
.     +++++ +++++ +   + +++++ +   + +++++ .
```

I "accidentally" ran this through `bf` and that came out

```
It's Me
```

*SCNR* :)

Comment: Interesting! :P

Answer (score 10):

## BASIC

slightly simplistic, but very true for those of us who stay up till 3 AM debugging...

```
On Error GoTo sleep
```

Comment: much nicer than PHP's `or die`

Answer (score 8):

### Python Love

```
def initely(there, were):
    if not None:
        atLeast = not "many"
    who.made("my heart")
    "beat as", you.do(_,_)
    return your.smile
warm = "ly"

try:
    toKeep = "it" + warm
    while walkingHome: pass
    ing(emptyWindows)
except:ionally = "sad"
finally: it = "'s over"

your = not any([1, "to me"]) or "just my toy" and \
type("",(), {"youWere": "more"} )()

your.smile = "kept me"
_ = warm in "these days"

but, you = "were failed by", your #love: me

if _: only(I)
hadKnown, you.were = "innocent as a", lambda \
young, blueEyed: \
[("but ", "the retribution") for myMisdoings #comes
in "time"]

sometimes, you.do = ("make me", #think of who
you.were) 
""in "another story"

I, who = "I've been", your#'s
"sit" in "my room"
"look"in"g at" #old photographs
#relentlessly remembering
the, love = you.do, "give to me"
who.made = all #these mistakes

"Had thought" + it + "would go"
on = "inf"+initely(
"Oh!, the", "fool I've")#been
regretting = all("my errors") #today

_, im = "hold" in "paraly","sys"
_ = open; "cans" and "cans of" 
_ = _(__import__(#ed beer
im).#in a d
argv[0]#id
).read() #sad poems

love, is_ = the, "thing I" #miss forever
iTake = "my camera"
go = "out to have"
new, photos = "to look", _ #at

print ("them" if 0 #they're dull
else _); "they make" + "me think of", love("lost", "for me")
```

EDIT: This is now a (if cheated) quine.

Answer (score 3):

bash or other shells on Unix or Linux:

```
who am I & whereis edit || eliza && find ada
```

Answer (score 2):

I really can't claim this one to myself, but I think it would be really good for you all to be able to look at it.

This is called PHP Sad Poem, and comes from [here](http://mundogris.wordpress.com/sad-php-poem/).

```
$timeWaiting = 0;
while (!$you->near($me)) {
    $me->thinkAbout($you);
    switch (true) {
        case $timeWaiting < 5:
            $me->wait($you);
            break;
        case $timeWaiting < 10:
            $me->worry();
            break;
        case $timeWaiting < 20:
            $me->lookFor($you);
            break;
        case $timeWaiting < 40:
            $me->worry();
            $me->lookFor($you);
            break;
        case $timeWaiting < 80:
            $me->worry();
            $me->cry();
            $me->lookFor($you);
            $me->lookFor($you);
            $me->lookFor($you);
            break;
        case $timeWaiting < 160:
            $me->worry();
            $me->cry();
            $me->drink();
            $me->lookFor($you);
            $me->lookFor($you);
            $me->lookFor($you);
            $me->thinkAbout($you);
            $me->thinkAbout($you);
            $me->cry();
            $me->lookFor($you);
            $me->lookFor($you);
            $me->drink();
            $me->drink();
            break;
        default:
            throw new CantLiveWithoutYou();
            die(“alone”);
        }
    $timeWaiting++;
}
$me->happy = true;
```